# How can I prevent an invalid file warning when running a Matlab code coverage report?

Tags: matlab, code-coverage

### Overview

I am getting a warning from Matlab's code coverage that a file is "invalid", and I would like to get rid of that warning.  I can think of two approaches, but I don't know how to accomplish either one.  My ideas are:

1. Fix the file so that the plugin does not flag it as invalid. (preferred)
2. Tell the Matlab code coverage plugin to ignore the file. (acceptable)

### Details

I have a file runTests.m that imports the Matlab code coverage plugin for unit tests:

```
import matlab.unittest.TestRunner
import matlab.unittest.plugins.CodeCoveragePlugin
import matlab.unittest.plugins.codecoverage.CoverageReport
```

When I run the tests, they all pass and the coverage report seems to have the correct information except for one App Designer file.  For that file, I get this warning:

```
Warning: Coverage result is empty for /MyPath/myApp.mlapp because the file is invalid.
```

How can I tell the code coverage plugin to ignore the App Designer .mlapp file?  The app works, so I don't know why it's invalid.  If I run the same test suite on a new blank app, there is no warning.

The rest of the warning output is:

```
In matlab.coverage.internal.ResultBuilder.createFromCodeCoverageCollectorData (line 20)
In matlab.coverage.internal/ResultBuilder/create (line 73)
In matlab.coverage.internal.getResults (line 11)
In matlab.unittest.internal.coverage.CodeCoverageCollector.get.Results (line 65)
In matlab.unittest.internal.plugins.CodeCoverageCollectionPlugin.runTestSuite/assignResultsAndResetProfilerCollector (line 25)
In matlab.unittest.internal.plugins.CodeCoverageCollectionPlugin>@()assignResultsAndResetProfilerCollector(plugin,pluginData.CommunicationBuffer) (line 22)
In onCleanup/delete (line 25)
In matlab.unittest.internal.plugins/CodeCoverageCollectionPlugin/runTestSuite (line 20)
In matlab.unittest.plugins/CodeCoveragePlugin/runTestSuite (line 350)
In matlab.unittest.plugins/TestRunnerPlugin/runTestSuite (line 265)
In matlab.unittest.plugins.xml/JUnitXMLOutputPlugin/runTestSuite (line 66)
In matlab.unittest/TestRunner/evaluateMethodOnPlugins (line 425)
In matlab.unittest.internal/SerialTestRunStrategy/runTestSuite (line 36)
In matlab.unittest.internal/SerialTestRunStrategy/runSession (line 16)
In matlab.unittest/TestRunner/runSession (line 1260)
In matlab.unittest.plugins/TestRunnerPlugin/runSession (line 228)
In matlab.unittest.plugins/CodeCoveragePlugin/runSession (line 345)
In matlab.unittest.plugins/TestRunnerPlugin/runSession (line 228)
In matlab.unittest.plugins.xml/JUnitXMLOutputPlugin/runSession (line 58)
In matlab.unittest/TestRunner/evaluateMethodOnPlugins (line 425)
In matlab.unittest/TestRunner/doRunWithFcn (line 413)
In matlab.unittest/TestRunner/run (line 297)
In runTests (line 55)
```